# How do I modify to add an Hour on time value in cell

Tags: vba, excel

I'm getting **`mismatch Error`** when I try adding 1 Hour to Time Value on cell **`"J8"`**

how do I modify to add an Hour?

```
With Range("J8")
    .Value = "='" & FilePath & "[Report.xlsm]Data'!J8" '// J8 = 02/12/2016 08:17 AM CST
    .Value = Mid(.Value, 12, 12)  '// J8 = 08:17 AM CST
    .Value = .Value + TimeSerial(1, 0, 0) ' <-- Error mismatch
End With
```

Comment: Maybe you could declare a variable to hold a time and assign to that variable (thus coercing the data as you go along) before you assign it to the range.

Comment: @JohnColeman that didn't work - I maybe doing something wrong, can you show some example?

Comment: It was just an idea. It isn't 100% clear what you are trying to do. Going from formula to value to modified value seems round about -- why don't you just read the value from the other workbook directly into a variant variable and then figure out how to modify it, perhaps using a `Debug.Print typenam(var)` to see how VBA is interpreting that value. Then after you modify the value as you want -- put it in the cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have to convert the time from a string yourself. The [Mid function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05e63829%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) is returning a string; convert that with the [TimeValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hz2ahtzs%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). TimeValue does not accept time zone abbreviations, so that will have to be stripped.

```
dim sTZ as string
With Range("J8")
    .Value = "='" & FilePath & "[Report.xlsm]Data'!J8" '// J8 = 02/12/2016 08:17 AM CST
    sTZ = Mid(.Value, 21, 3)
    .Value = TimeValue(Mid(.Value, 12, 8))  '// J8 = 08:17 AM (No time zone)
    .Value = .Value + TimeSerial(1, 0, 0) ' <-- Time is added to time; no mismatch
    'optionally put the time zone back in
    '.value = .value & chr(32) & sTZ
    'optionally keep the time as time and format the time zone back in
    '.numberformat = "hh:mm AM/PM C\ST"
End With
```

If maintaining a relationship with UTC time is mission critical, then you will have to concatenate the time zone information off the back end. This will turn the time value in a string representing the time with time zone. Conversion to a string could be avoided if you simply changed the [Range.NumberFormat property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196401.aspx).

It may not be practical to hardcode a large number of time zones into custom number formats. The following builds a custom number format with the appropriate time zone from the original text-that-looks-like-a-time.

```
Dim sTZ As String, sTZmask As String
With Range("J8")
    .Value = "='" & FilePath & "[Report.xlsm]Data'!J8" '// J8 = 02/12/2016 08:17 AM CST
    sTZ = Mid(.Value, 21, 3)
    'split the time zone and stitch it back together with the number format escape character
    sTZmask = Join(Split(StrConv(Chr(32) & sTZ, vbUnicode), vbNullChar), Chr(92))
    'remove any trailing escape characters
    Do While Right(sTZmask, 1) = Chr(92): sTZmask = Left(sTZmask, Len(sTZmask) - 1): Loop
    .Value = TimeValue(Mid(.Value, 12, 8))  '// J8 = 08:17 AM (No time zone)
    .Value = .Value + TimeSerial(1, 0, 0) ' <-- Time is added to time; no mismatch
    'keep the time as time and format the time zone back in
    .NumberFormat = "hh:mm AM/PM" & sTZmask
End With
```

Comment: Very interesting info, Thanx Jeeped

Answer (score 0):

```
With Range("J8")
    .Value = "='" & FilePath & "[Report.xlsm]Data'!J8" '// J8 = 02/12/2016 08:17 AM CST
    .Value = TimeValue(Mid(.Value, 12, 8))  '// J8 = 08:17 AM CST
    .NumberFormat = "hh:mm AM/PM C\ST"
    .Value = .Value + TimeSerial(1, 0, 0) '// Add 1 Hour 09:17
End With
```

Thanks Jeeped